# sqlite3 not found but it was already added as reference

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sqlite, dllnotfoundexception

> System.DllNotFoundException was unhandled Message=Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found.

I already reference the DLL. I check it on Debug folder and it was there. I also search how to "include" it in the project but they don't specifically explain how to do it.

I'm following this example:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22165/Using-SQLite-in-your-C-Application

Comment: Is the .dll being copied into the output (default "bin") directory?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite doesn't have a full .NET implementation, but available libraries are wrappers of a native one.

This means that not only .NET assembly must be referenced but you need to be sure native library is there too when applicacion is executed.

Summary: output folder will have a .NET assembly and a native assembly (C/C++ one) in order to work properly!

Comment: i'm following this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22165/Using-SQLite-in-your-C-Application

for sure they didn't post something that won't work

Comment: @JoefClarin Relax and instead of saying that, double-check what I said. I came here to give you a solution. Maybe I'm wrong, but my current understanding of SQLite on .NET is what I said.

Comment: @JoefClarin that page is from 2007 and uses a .NET SQLite implementation that hasn't been updated since 2005. Not the best reference material. The current official SQLite wrapper for C# can be found at http://system.data.sqlite.org (maintained by SQLite team)

Comment: @JoefClarin In addition, if you read MORE the whole article you'll find that definitive sentence: **•SQLite has native language APIs for C/C++, PHP, Perl, Python, Tcl etc. Native API for C# is still not present.**.

Comment: @dtech Yeah, and later you find that you want to help him, and he's completely wrong with his comment of "for sure they didn't post something that won't work".............

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Data.SQLite.dll` is platform dependent assembly, and you mast add reference to appropriated assembly.

Comment: already added it as reference. it won't build if i didn't add the proper reference

Comment: The metadatas is same(which needs at compile time) in both x86 and x64 wrappers, therefore the project will build, but runtime exception will occurs when accessing the not proper dll.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps :

1)Add the Dll in debug folder
2)in your code add this

using System.Data.SQLite;
3) Add the reference by going to solution explorer and add it.

4) Check the version in app.config to verify it